# React: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop persists with unique keys

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the react error for not passing a unique key to a rendered list.

As far as I can tell, I'm passing a unique key to the outer-level element within the list, so if anyone can identify what the issue is and how to fix it I'd appreciate it.

I suspect it might be the way I'm returning the list. The original array has an empty obj inserted in at pos 1, then when I map over the array I  return a component *Feed* at index 1, and return the original items otherwise. Would the two returns be the issue here?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { fetchStories } from '../actions/index';
import Snippets from './Snippets';




const Stories = ({ stories, fetchStories }) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStories();
  }, [fetchStories]);

  const emptyObj = {};

  //creates a new array with empy obj at pos 1, when mapping this we'll insert the Feed component at pos 1
  const storiesArrayWithFeed = () => {

    const copyStories = [...stories];
    copyStories.splice(1, 0, emptyObj);
    return copyStories
  }

  //renders the array of user stories into grid items, but inserts feed component into position 1 in index 
  const renderGrid = () => {
    const storiesWithFeed = storiesArrayWithFeed();
    return storiesWithFeed.map((story, index) => {
      if (index === 1) {
        return (
          <div className={`stories-grid-item story-item `} key={index}>
            <Snippets />
          </div>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <div className={`stories-grid-item story-item`} key={story._id}>
            <Link
              to={`/stories/${story._id}`}
            >
              <h3>{story.title}</h3>
              <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `${story.sanitizedHtml}` }}
                className="story-page-story">
              </p>
            </Link>
          </div>
        )
      }
    })
  }





  return (
    <div className="stories-container">
      <h1>Latest Stories</h1>
      <div className="stories-grid author-stories-grid">
        {renderGrid()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


const mapStateToProps = ({ stories }) => {
  return { stories }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStories })(Stories);
```

Comment: Try `key={-1}` instead of `key={index}`

Comment: Still get the error. The other keys are mongodb ids so there shouldn't be duplication with key as index value

Comment: Maybe you have duplicating id-s? try printing id-s instead of `story.title` for example, just to check

Comment: Still get the error. The answer by crispen below solves the issue. I think there's a race condition in using properties from the stories array, when I log a property from the story in the loop it returns an undefined, then the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this from

```
<div className={`stories-grid-item story-item`} key={story._id}>
```

to

```
<div className={`stories-grid-item story-item`} key={index}>
```

**Goof luck, let me know if it works**

Comment: Solves my issue! I think the problem is a race condition when mapping over the stories array, because if I console log the properties I want to use as keys I get undefined, then I get the properties...

Comment: I Awesome, enjoy coding buddy